# Creating Foursquare Business page for the developers

Tags: foursquare

My application will be integrated with the foursquare. For this purpose, I need to use the foursquare business page (https://foursquare.com/business/merchants).

In order to use, i need to verify that i am a manager or the people related to that organization to claim the venue. But I am student and the developer. So how can i use that foursquare business page for my study purpose.

I want that foursquare business page because i want to provide my custom instruction when somebody just checks-in into that venue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foursquare does not have a sandbox environment, nor do they allow for test venues. What you need to do is create your code and send test push notifications to it. This page details what a push notification looks like: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime